# Sign up form (Registration) in android app to check username uniqueness

Tags: android, authentication, registration

I am developing an app which requires me to use login using either fb account or sign up. I have created the sign up page which contains the following fields

1. Name
2. Username
3. Password
4. Confirm password
5. email

When the control goes to password field, I want the app to return whether the enterd username is already taken or not.
I want to develop it in android and toast a message or display alert. How can we check username authentication ? Is there any app which performs similar sign up function and checks username verification ? Kindly let me know. 
I have created a local db where the username and password are placed. When a new user uses the same username, it must go to the db and check if its taken and throw an error.

Comment: I need to put an image beside username box like "checked" or "unchecked" depending on the availability. I found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494241/android-ajax-style-auto-check-of-username-availability) pretty helpful so thought of sharing it with others.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an OnFocusChangeListener to check if the username is unique.

```java
editTextUsername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            //check if username is unique
            //set the image
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: I think OnFocusChangeListener would be best way to do this task

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database on the `onClick` event of the `Submit` button. I am assuming that you have a `Submit` button.

Comment: Yes Aki I do have a submit and a local database which takes care of the logins. But I am not getting how to check the validation when the program shift flows from one edittext to another

Comment: In that case, you should try out the `onFocusChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextWatcher

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

You can associate a TextWatcher with an EditText like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher{ //put the implementation here  });
```

Fire your request to the web service/database at the end of the afterTextChanged() method, and preferably do it asynchronously. Text fields tend to have their content changed pretty frequently and you don't want to be doing heavy operations like communicating with a web service or doing a database query on the applications main thread.